# native ES6 Promises in browser vs. Node (asynchrony)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

It looks like ES6 [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are async by default, without the need to use `process.nextTick` in Node (unlike `events` for instance).

e.g.:

```
Promise.resolve('foo').then(function a() {
    console.log('bar');
});

console.log('baz');
```

"baz" gets logged before "bar" so it appears to be async.

With Node.js, internally this could be accomplished via `process.nextTick` or what not.

However, with the browser, how is the asynchrony achieved with native promises? Is it with setTimeout or some other facility?

We can also see that this is async as well:

```
new Promise(function(resolve){
     resolve('foo');  //called synchronously
}).then(function(){
     console.log('bar');
});

console.log('baz');
```

("baz" will get logged first)

Comment: Your asking us about browser internals?  How would we know that?

Comment: I will take an educated guess

Comment: "However, with the browser, how is the asynchrony achieved with native promises? Is it with setTimeout or some other facility?" - No, because they are implemented in native code, not in JavaScript, so no `setTimeout`.

Comment: When you say async, what do you mean by that?

Comment: right, the callback function (I just named it "a") does not get called until later

Comment: If you're just talking about reordering instructions, you don't even need separate threads for that.  Normally, you would use a promise that returns a result based on some external event, like an AJAX call.  So really, you don't even need a timer tick.

Comment: this is just a simple question about if and how aPromise.then() is asynchronous in the browser :)

Comment: Which I gave a simple answer for.

Comment: well then sorry I don't follow

Comment: OK.  You know how a promise works from a programmer's point of view, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109867/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-alex-mills).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .